# imprimir mais de 1 cookie

Tags: php

estou com uma duvida aqui e não estou conseguindo resolver uma vez que eu sou iniciante em php.

Eu quero recuperar cookies e imprimir na tela um determinado valor que corresponde ao cookie, porém eu só consigo imprimir 1 cookie.

```
Página que eu estou pegando o cookie 
<?php
    setcookie("Nome",$Valor,(time() + (7 * 24 * 3600 )));
    $_COOKIE["Nome"];
?>

Página que eu estou exibindo os cookie
<?php
    $Test = $_COOKIE["Nome"];

    print_r($Test);
?>
```

eu já tentei echo no lugar de "print_r" e não funcionou

Comment: Não deu pra entender muito bem, você só está declarando 1 cookie, qual outro você quer mostrar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize um foreach para retornar todos os cookies. Dessa forma você vai poder identificar todos os nomes e valores dos cookies e daí poder recuperar os que necessitar para sua aplicação.

```
foreach ($_COOKIE as $key => $value) {
  print($key.' - '.$value.'<br>');
};
```

> Por padrão, o cookie poderá ser utilizado no diretório onde foi criado e em seus subdiretórios. Se indicamos "/" o cookie terá validade dentro de todo o domínio.

```
setcookie("Nome",  $Valor, (time() + (7 * 24 * 3600)), "/");
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. vlw msm